# Deleting a Specific Item from multiple listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox, contextmenustrip

I'm trying to delete a specific item from multiple listBoxes.
I've created a ContextMenuStrip which contains a **Delete** Button.

I can delete the listbox item by clicking a right click on the mouse and pressing the delete button on the ContextMenuStrip.
But I would be happy to know if I can do it on multiple Listboxes.

This it the writing button code:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Hello");
```

this it the delete button code:

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
listBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: `lst.items.Remove(lst.selectedIndex)` - something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before showing the contextMenu, you can set the tag property to the listbox you clicked:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Tag = listBox1;
contextMenuStrip1.Show();
```

Then, on the Opened event, cast to a ListBox and remove the item:

```
var lb = ((ListBox)contextMenuStrip1.Tag);
lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);
```